# React redux Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm getting data from the backend (Node) and not able to display a nested object, I've tried to use map but even there I got the same issue/error message.

here is my code or better to same the component.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import cookie from 'react-cookie';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {fetchUser} from '../../../actions/index';

import UserInfo from './user-info';

class ViewProfile extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    if (cookie.load('user')) {
      const userId = cookie.load('user')._id;
      this.props.fetchUser(userId);
    }
  }


  render() {
    let test = this.props.user.profile.firstName;
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.props.user.email}</h1>
        {test}
      </div>

    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    user: state.user.profile
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchUser})(ViewProfile);
```

#### Here's the error

```
bundle.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined(…)
```

I'm getting a object back from the server, it has a the following structure:

```
{_id: ...,
 email: ...,
 profile:{firstName: 'a', lastName:'b'},....
}
```

I want to display the name. How Can I do archive that?

### UPDATE 1

I'm sending via the reducer the following:

```
....
case FETCH_USER:
  return {...state, profile: action.payload};
```

### solution

```
  renderUserInfo() {
    if (this.props.user.profile) {
      return (
        <UserInfo profile={this.props.user.profile}/>
      )
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.props.user.email}</h1>
        {this.renderUserInfo()}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: could you also post more of your reducer code, I mean how the function looks like and how are you initialising state in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if fetchUser() is an async function then this.props.user will be undefined inside render() while the user is being fetched. You can add this at the beginning of render()

```
if(!this.props.user) { // or !this.props.user.profile depending on your initialState
   return null; 
}
```

Comment: ohh exactly it has been a long time ago that I have code in react! Is not possible to use `defaultProps` for that kind of problem?

Comment: You can, but if you are using Redux I'd use a default value in the reducer's initial state instead just to keep all state managed in one place.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're dealing with async operation. You can dispatch an action of type FETCH_USER when you're don with fetching the data. But it's always better to multiple action type to describe what fetching state you're in. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Td-2D-_7Y2E) is an example of how to deal with async operation.

Comment: thanks for sharing ... The approach is looking good but what about a big app, then you have to make a lot work here...

Comment: Yes, but I'd still like to take care of all the corner cases. I understand it gets boring to write a lot of boilerplate codes. But you can write helper functions to reduce some of them.